# Multiple aggregate sums from different conditions in one sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Whereas I believe this is a fairly general SQL question, I am working in PostgreSQL 9.4 without an option to use other database software, and thus request that any answer be compatible with its capabilities.

I need to be able to return multiple aggregate totals from one query, such that each sum is in a new row, and each of the groupings are determined by a unique span of time, e.g. `WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-02-07' AND '2016-02-14'`. The number of records that satisfy there `WHERE` clause is unknown and may be zero, in which case ideally the result is "0". This is what I have worked out so far:

```
(
SELECT SUM(minutes) AS min
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-02-07' AND '2016-02-14'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT SUM(minutes)
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-02-14' AND '2016-02-21'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT SUM(minutes)
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-02-28' AND '2016-03-06'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT SUM(minutes)
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-03-06' AND '2016-03-13'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT SUM(minutes))
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-03-13' AND '2016-03-20'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT SUM(minutes)
FROM downtime
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-03-20' AND '2016-03-27'
)
```

Result:

```
     min
---+-----
 1 | 119
 2 |   4
 3 |  30
 4 |   
 5 |  62 
 6 | 350
```

That query gets me *almost* the exact result that I want; certainly good enough in that I can do exactly what I need with the results. Time spans with no records are blank but that was predictable, and whereas I would prefer "0" I can account for the blank rows in software.

But, while it isn't terrible for the 6 weeks that it represents, I want to be flexible and to be able to do the same thing for different time spans, and for a different number of data points, such as each day in a week, each week in 3 months, 6 months, each month in 1 year, 2 years, etc... As written above, it feels as if it is going to get tedious fast... for instance 1 week spans over a 2 year period is 104 sub-queries.

What I'm after is a more elegant way to get the same (or similar) result.

I also don't know if doing 104 iterations of a similar query to the above (vs. the 6 that it does now) is a particularly efficient usage.

Ultimately I am going to write some code which will help me build (and thus abstract away) the long, ugly query--but it would still be great to have a more concise and scale-able query.

Comment: I don't think your query does what you think it does.  `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so the boundaries are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can generate a series of times and then use these for the aggregation:

```
select g.dte, coalesce(sum(dt.minutes), 0) as minutes
from generate_series('2016-02-07'::timestamp, '2016-03-20'::timestamp, interval '7 day') g(dte) left join
     downtime dt
     on dt.timestamp >= g.dte and dt.timestamp < g.dte + interval '7 day'
group by g.dte
order by g.dte;
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Allow me a moment to work with it before I accept your answer but this appears to be the very thing I wanted.